# S3 and CloudFront hosting a static website, with each page reload resulting in a 403 error

Tags: html, amazon-s3, next.js, server, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently hosting a static HTML and CSS website by utilizing `Next.js export` and deploying it to both S3 and CloudFront. The file structure comprises pages such as `blog/index.html, page2/index.html, and page3/index.html.`

While navigating from the navbar to access the 'about' page ([www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog)), the page functions correctly. However, upon reloading, an issue arises, and a 403 status is returned from S3-CloudFront.

Is there a potential solution for this error within the current setup, or should I consider changing the server architecture to address this issue?